# UIImageView from Storyboard nil on simulator

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, storyboard

I have a quite normally wired UIImageView in a viewController in a StoryBoard. When I run the app on the iPhone it is correctly assigned in the code, while if if I run in the simulator it remains nil thus crashing the constraint trying to locate it. That would not be a big deal, were it not for the need of producing the screenshots for the iPhone 5 I do not own.
All other objects are correctly loaded also on the simulator.
The name is "appending" that I do not think is a reserved word, and I tried also to load a different image in the control with not variation.

What could it be?

Comment: Try running a clean...

Comment: I did it many times, the strange thing is that it does not happen with the english version, notwithstanding now I have a single storyboard for all languages in order to better handle modifications.

Comment: Strangely it just happens to the languages I previously had as separate storyboards, while the new ones work fine like the english one. Is there a way to refresh the xibs?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't wired up the UIImageView in the other storyboards. It's not automatic...

Comment: I just have just one iPhone storyboard now.

Comment: In fact the problem seems to be connected to the old localized storyboards. Once reestablished, the image acquired a value. Yet another Apple bug. They should pay me, I think.